# How to install jvmr package on databricks

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark

I want to call R function in scala script on databricks. Is there anyway that we can do it?

I use

```
JVMR_JAR=$(R --slave -e 'library("jvmr"); cat(.jvmr.jar)')
scalac -cp "$JVMR_JAR"
scala -cp ".:$JVMR_JAR"
```

on my mac and it automatically open a scala which can call R functions. 
Is there any way I can do similar stuff on databricks?

Comment: What do you mean "*on databricks*"? Are you using the [Databricks cloud](https://databricks.com/product/databricks) ?

Comment: yes, I am using Databricks cloud.

Answer (score 0):

On the DataBricks Cloud, you can use the sbt-databricks to deploy external libraries to the cloud and attach them to specific clusters, which are two necessary steps to make sure jvmr is available to the machines you're calling this on.

See the plugin's [github](https://github.com/databricks/sbt-databricks) README and [the blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/05/making-databricks-cloud-better-for-developers-ide-integration.html).

If those resources don't suffice, perhaps you should ask your questions to  Databricks' support.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an R function in the scala notebook, you can use the `%r` shortcut.

```
df.registerTempTable("temp_table_scores")
```

Create a new cell, then use:

```
%r
scores <- table(sqlContext, "temp_table_scores")
local_df <- collect(scores)    
someFunc(local_df)
```

If you want to pass the data back into the environment, you can save it to S3 or register it as a temporary table.